# StreamWriter to project directory and sub directory?

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I'm currently having an issue with my application and I'm starting to think it's just my logic. I can't figure it out even after browsing these forms and MSDN.

I'm trying to use StreamWriter to create a text document in my app directory and create sub folder containing that document. Currently it just keeps dumping the file in my apps exe directory.

```
        string runTimeDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

        string recipeDirectory = Path.Combine(runTimeDirectory, "Recipes");
        if (!Directory.Exists(recipeDirectory))
        {
            //Recipes directory doesnt exist so create it
            Directory.CreateDirectory(recipeDirectory);
        }

        // Write text to file
        using (StreamWriter OutputFile = new StreamWriter(recipeDirectory + RecipeName + @".txt"))
        {
```

Comment: Just a guess, but `recipeDirectory` probably doesn't end with a `\` so you end up with: `C:\foo\Recpiesmyrecipe.txt` rather than: `C:\foo\Recipies\myrecipie.txt"

Comment: That's correct, it's creating the file + the file directory name. I see my issue in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
using (StreamWriter OutputFile = new StreamWriter(
    Path.Combine(recipeDirectory,  RecipeName + @".txt")))
```

The reason I think is that your `recipeDirectory` and `RecipeName + @".txt"` aren't separated by the backslash, so the file is written to the parent directory instead and named `recipeDirectory + RecipeName + @".txt"`.

As an aside, I would also recommend you pass your `RecipeName` through a sanitizer function like this in case any name contains characters that can't be used in a file name:

```
internal static string GetSafeFileName(string fromString)
{
    var invalidChars = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars();
    const char ReplacementChar = '_';

    return new string(fromString.Select((inputChar) => 
        invalidChars.Any((invalidChar) => 
        (inputChar == invalidChar)) ? ReplacementChar : inputChar).ToArray());
}
```

Comment: I thought the same, but you would think this would be obvious in that the created file would have the wonky name.

Comment: Doesn't `Path.Combine` do that for you?

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre Yes, but the OP wasn't using that.  That's what *my* answer added...

Comment: @roryap Oh yes, sorry, I read it earlier in their code so thought that was also in there already

Comment: @roryap Thank you! That did the trick, that's exactly what I was trying to do.

Comment: @JosephOliveri -- you're welcome.  I just added an (important) update to my answer for your review also.